# The usage of a static method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

I recently came across a code for make bar plots and I am wondering why is there a need for a static method for a function in python. On top of that why self.function_name is used for a staticmethod. Here is the code :

```
class Foo :
    @staticmethod
    def make_bar_plot(values, labels, title, ylabel='Activity Count', step=10):

        x_pos = np.arange(len(labels))

        plt.bar(x_pos, values, align='center', alpha=0.5)
        plt.xticks(x_pos, labels)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(0, max(values) + step, step))

        plt.ylabel(ylabel)
        plt.title(title)

        for index, val in enumerate(values):
            plt.text(x=index, y=val+1, s=f'{val}')

        plt.show()
    def get_daywise_activity_stats(self, event_name, no_of_days):

        query = """select edate, count(*)
                    from %s
                        where ip_address not in (
                            select distinct(ip_address)
                            from activity_classic_class_section_start
                                where edate <'2019-12-31')
                        group by edate order by edate desc limit %s;
                        """%(event_name, no_of_days)

        event_dict = {ele[0].strftime("%m/%d/%Y"):ele[1] for ele in self.rs_conn.query(query)}
        print (event_dict)

        labels = list(event_dict.keys())
        values = list(event_dict.values())
        self.make_bar_plot(values, labels, 'Daywise_activity_stats -> '+event_name)
```

Doesn't static methods work without self.function_name and work with class_name.function_name or am I missing something important here?

Comment: If you're asking what the motivation was for someone using a static method in a particular way, you might have to direct your question to the author of the code.

Comment: Static methods mean you can call them from outside the class, without making an instance. You still need to reference them, and it's easier to call `self.make_bar_plot` than `Foo.make_bar_plot`, especially as if `Foo` is inherited from, `self.make_bar_plot` will call the child's method (if overwritten).

Comment: Thanks .This makes sense, it clears the confusion I had about references made in static methods. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could also call `make_bar_plot` in a follwoing way:

```
Foo.make_bar_plot(values, labels, 'Daywise_activity_stats -> '+event_name)
```

It will be the same as your code. 
You need to reference your class - you can do it either by `self`, because every instance of the class will have a reference to `make_bar_plot` static method, or by giving the class name `FOO`. The result will be the same.